# Animation - How to turn animated values into real values via interpolate

Tags: animation, react-native

I'm trying to simultaneously restrict the values of my animation (using clamp as well as interpolate) but also get the values out of the interpolation so I can use them. Specifically because I want to update a piece of state with them and create an observable from that. I just can't figure out how to extract the 'real' value out of the AnimatedValue that is produced by the interpolation (in this case state.panValue). I've tried

```
this.state.panValue.value
```

and

```
this.state.panValue._value
```

and they come back as undefined. If anyone could help me out would be amazing!

**EDIT:** I'd also be really happy to just have the

```
this.state.pan.x
```

variable updated within the limits so I can skip the whole updating the state variable 'panValue' thing. A nice guy on Facebook suggested that I could implement this limit somehow inside the onPanResponderMove by switching the variable to a function or something but I've tried several things and all I get are errors, I guess because I don't really know how to 'safely' amend these animated values.

```
      onPanResponderMove: Animated.event([
      null,
      { dx: this.state.pan.x },
    ]),
```

Original Code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  View,
  Animated,
  PanResponder,
  Text,
} from 'react-native';
import styles from './styles';

class ClockInSwitch extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
   super(props);
   this.state = {
   pan: new Animated.ValueXY(),
   panValue: 0,
  };
 }

componentWillMount() {
 this._animatedValueX = 0;
 this._animatedValueY = 0;
 this.state.pan.x.addListener((value) => {
   this._animatedValueX = value.value;
    this.setState({
        panValue: this.state.pan.x.interpolate({
          inputRange: [-30, 0, 120,],
          outputRange: [-10, 0, 120,],
          extrapolate: 'clamp',
        }),
    });
});

this._panResponder = PanResponder.create({
  // Ask to be the responder:
  onStartShouldSetPanResponder: (evt, gestureState) => true,
  onStartShouldSetPanResponderCapture: (evt, gestureState) => true,
  onMoveShouldSetPanResponder: (evt, gestureState) => true,
  onMoveShouldSetPanResponderCapture: (evt, gestureState) => true,

  onPanResponderGrant: (evt, gestureState) => {
    this.state.pan.setOffset({
      x: this._animatedValueX,
    });
    this.state.pan.setValue({ x: 0, y: 0 });
  },
  onPanResponderMove: Animated.event([
      null,
      { dx: this.state.pan.x },
    ]),
  onPanResponderTerminationRequest: (evt, gestureState) => true,
  onPanResponderRelease: (evt, gestureState) => {
    this.state.pan.flattenOffset();
    Animated.timing(this.state.pan, {
      toValue: 0,
      duration: 500,
    }).start();
  },
  onPanResponderTerminate: (evt, gestureState) => {
  },
  onShouldBlockNativeResponder: (evt, gestureState) => {
    return true;
  },
 });
}

componentWillUnMount() {
  this.state.pan.x.removeAllListeners();
}

render() {
   const animatedStyle = {
    transform: [{
    translateX: this.state.panValue,
    },
    ],
  };
return (
  <View>
    <Text>{this.state.pan.x._value}</Text>
    <View style={styles.buttonStyle}>
      <Animated.View
        style={[styles.sliderButtonStyle, animatedStyle]}
        {...this._panResponder.panHandlers}
      />
    </View>
  </View>
   );
  }
}

export default ClockInSwitch;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for.  I'm using exponent so your declaration for vector icons would probably need to be changed.  Cheers!

```js
/**
 * @providesModule ClockInSwitch
 * @flow
 */
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {View, Animated, StyleSheet, PanResponder, Text} from 'react-native';
import {FontAwesome} from '@exponent/vector-icons';

export class ClockInSwitch extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            pan: new Animated.ValueXY(),
            panValue: 0
        };
    }
    componentWillMount() {
        this._panResponder = PanResponder.create({
            onMoveShouldSetResponderCapture: () => true,
            onMoveShouldSetPanResponderCapture: () => true,
            onPanResponderGrant: (e, gestureState) => {
                this
                    .state
                    .pan
                    .setValue({x: 0, y: 0});
            },
            //here's where you can check, constrain and store values
            onPanResponderMove: (evt, gestureState) => {
                // 300 is the width of the red container (will leave it to you to calculate this
                // dynamically) 100 is the width of the button (90) plus the 5px margin on
                // either side of it (10px total)
                var newXVal = (gestureState.dx < 300 - 100)
                    ? gestureState.dx
                    : 300 - 100;
                this
                    .state
                    .pan
                    .x
                    .setValue(newXVal);
                //set this state for display
                this.setState({panValue: newXVal});
            },

            onPanResponderRelease: (e, {vx, vy}) => {
                this
                    .state
                    .pan
                    .flattenOffset();
                Animated
                    .spring(this.state.pan, {
                    toValue: 0,
                    duration: 400,
                    overshootClamping: true
                })
                    .start();
                this.setState({panValue: 0});
            }
        });
    }

    componentWillUnMount() {
        this
            .state
            .pan
            .x
            .removeAllListeners();
    }

    render() {
        //decouple the value from the state object
        let {pan} = this.state;
        let [translateX,
            translateY] = [pan.x, pan.y];
        let translateStyle = {
            transform: [{
                    translateX
                }, {
                    translateY
                }]
        };
        return (
            <View>
                <Text style={styles.leftText}>Power Button Demo</Text>
                <View style={styles.buttonStyle}>
                    <Animated.View
                        style={[styles.sliderButtonStyle, translateStyle]}
                        {...this._panResponder.panHandlers}>
                        <FontAwesome
                            name="power-off"
                            color="#EA2E49"
                            style={{
                            alignSelf: "center",
                            marginHorizontal: 10
                        }}
                            size={36}/>

                    </Animated.View>
                </View>
                <Text style={styles.rightText}>{this.state.panValue}: x value</Text>
            </View>
        );
    }
}

export default ClockInSwitch;
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    sliderButtonStyle: {
        borderColor: '#FCFFF5',
        borderStyle: 'solid',
        borderWidth: .5,
        backgroundColor: '#FCFFF5',
        borderRadius: 45,
        height: 90,
        width: 90,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        textAlign: 'center',
        marginHorizontal: 5,
        shadowColor: '#333745',
        shadowOffset: {
            width: 2,
            height: 2
        },
        shadowOpacity: .6,
        shadowRadius: 5
    },
    buttonStyle: {
        borderColor: '#FCFFF500',
        backgroundColor: '#DAEDE255',
        borderStyle: 'solid',
        borderWidth: 1,
        height: 100,
        width: 300,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        borderRadius: 50,
        margin: 5,
        flexDirection: 'column'
    },
    rightText: {
        justifyContent: 'center',
        textAlign: 'right',
        fontWeight: '100',
        marginHorizontal:15,
        fontSize: 20,
        color: '#FCFFF5',
        marginVertical:25,
        flexDirection: 'column'
    },
    leftText: {
        justifyContent: 'center',
        textAlign: 'left',
        fontWeight: '100',
        marginHorizontal:15,
        fontSize: 24,
        color: '#FCFFF5',
        marginVertical:25,
        flexDirection: 'column'
    }
});
```